# Why does the Open API Generator produce different class names from the ones in the OAS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an OAS YAML file, and the Maven plugin generates POJO classes for me.

However, it adds words to the class names of the POJO classes. In the OAS, the schema is defined with the name "ApiResponse," but the plugin generates it as "ModelApiResponse" in the Java class.

How should I configure the plugin to create a POJO class with the name specified in the OAS?

The current config of the plugin is:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
     <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>6.6.0</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>target-spec</id>
               <goals>
               <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
          <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petstore.yaml</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <modelPackage>com.petstorespringapi.stub.target</modelPackage>
            <generateApis>false</generateApis>
            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is my petstore.yml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
paths:
  '/pet/{petId}/uploadImage':
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Uploads an image
      description: ''
      operationId: uploadFile
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: ID of pet to update
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                additionalMetadata:
                  description: Additional data to pass to server
                  type: string
                file:
                  description: file to upload
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                '$ref': '#/components/schemas/ApiResponse'
components:
  schemas:
    ApiResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        type:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
```

Here is the generated class:

```
/**
 * ModelApiResponse
 */

@JsonTypeName("ApiResponse")
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-08-12T11:49:39.983257+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]")
public class ModelApiResponse {}
```

Comment: My advice would be, if you start a new project it is ok to use openapi3. But if you migrate your stack specially this combo (spring boot 3 , gradle 8 and java>= 17), so just wait a little bit, take a look at open issues for openapi you will understand if it worth it or not.